# Android add flag on button click

Tags: android, button, canvas

I have a button and I want when I click on it the flag.png image gets created and I place it anywhere on the canvas

this is my flag button code

```
        // the flag button
    Button flag = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFlag1);
    flag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        flag(R.drawable.flag1);
        }
        });
```

and this is my function

```
public void flag(int resourceID) {
    Bitmap flagBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), resourceID);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(flagBitmap);
    c.drawBitmap(flagBitmap, null, null);
}
```

nothing happens atm ..

the flags are circle and I have them as buttons, and what I want is them to be added when each button is clicked its flag is inserted and I can put it where I want

Like a smiley on any photo editing app

Comment: If you didn't understand, read it as: I want when my flag button is clicked, a flag image (flag.pnG) gets inserted on the imageview and I place it where I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you mentioned using an imageview in your question while what you're using is canvas to draw a bitmap image. If you want to do it the imageview-way, here's some code to help you out:

```
ImageView pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Bitmap img=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.flag1);
pic.setImageBitmap(img);
```

Make sure to declare your imageview in the xml file. Feel free to comment if there are any further questions or if I got your question wrong.

**Edit:**

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.reset();
matrix.postTranslate(x, y);

pic.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
pic.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Instead of x and y, insert the x and y co-ordinates where you want to place the flag.

Comment: My advice is don't use a canvas, if you want to move the imageview to the desired location. See the edit above.

Comment: Ok, thanks =), but I really prefer canvas .. umm maybe u didn't understand my goal ..